# How to get the whole (parent) element not just the specific child after using e.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

In the code below I want to target the `li` to see if that `li` was clicked. Currently, when I click on the text of the `li` the e.target is the span, which is the child of the li, so it is like I'm not clicking on the li (I guess e.target is very specific). The li is in a drop down menu so i am using e.target to get which option the user wants. If the user picks li with a class 1 set global variable. If the user picks li with a class of 2 set a diff global variable. What,s the best way to target the whole li?

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
        var clicked = ["subtraction"]
        $(".add-section").on("click", function(e){
            console.log(e.target)
            clicked = []
            clicked[0] = "addition"
            $("#gameArea").html(clicked[0])
            if(!$(".add-section ul").is(":visible")){
                $(".add-section ul").css("display" , "block")
            }else{
                $(".add-section ul").slideUp("fast")
            }
            if($(e.target).hasClass("one")){
                alert("one")
            }
        })
    });
```

html:

```
<div class="add-section">
    <span>add</span>
    <ul>
        <li class="one"><span class = "left" id = "add2">Add 2 items</span> <span class= "right">2d</span></li>
        <li class= "two"><span class = "left" id="add3">Add 3 items</span> <span class= "right">2d</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not add the click event to the span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of:

```
$(e.target).hasClass("one")
```

use:

```
$(e.target).closest('li').is('.one')
```

[**.is() | jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/is/)
[**.closest() | jQuery API Documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `e.target.parentNode`

Comment: the alert happens when i click on the word "add". I think because the parent node is the div "class="add-section""